# jquery event logged. how does it work exactly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was searching in jquery api.documentation and found this code example:

```
var event = jQuery.Event( "logged" );
event.user = "foo";
event.pass = "bar";
$( "body" ).trigger( event );
```

I was trying to understand how this can interact with html code... but it looks impossible to me... and I'm still stunned

Can anyone explain something about? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of custom event handling. jQuery allows to bind not only to DOM events like usual `onclick`, `onkeyup`, etc. but also any custom user defined events. For example:

```js
$("body").on("logged", function(e) {
    alert('Logged: ' + e.user + ', ' + e.pass);
});

var event = jQuery.Event("logged");
event.user = "foo";
event.pass = "bar";
$( "body" ).trigger( event );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok.. Then, I can create an _event "logged"_ and shoot it with _$.trigger()_.. And what are _user_ and _pass_ doing?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes They become properties of the event object. Check updated demo.

Comment: So, Can I deduct that this is the same as: _var logged = function(args){} ?_

Comment: No, pubsub (events) allows you to write much less coupled code. Say you have two modules. One module subscribes to event, and other publish it. This way modules don' have to know about each other at all. Events are very powerful pattern.